# How to show PDF file inside html file in Android Studio without Internet Connectivity

Tags: android, pdf-reader

I am building a new Android application which contains lots of Pdf files. So if I use Pdf libraries like barteskc my app may become huge sized. So is there any codes or less sized library for me to include PDF reader inside my app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show PDF file in App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170975/show-pdf-file-in-app)

Comment: hello @Abdul Fathah instead of html file you should use webview to load PDF file