# Android - how prompt user to choose an external program for rendering a file

Tags: android

I am writing a program for Android which has PDF / ODT file with instructions (yes, those are complex). Actually, I am planning how to do it... So, let's say, a user taps on menu entry "View Instructions" and he should get a prompt which asks to choose an external app for viewing the file (I assume that viewing PDF/ODT file inside my program is extremely complex task, so I find it acceptable to delegate it to another app), - and chosen program pops up with opened file for viewing. How do I implement such behavior?

I have very limited experience at programming Android, I have written a program which interfaced with camera. From that time I remember that I called something like Activity... or Intent... I don't remember. Anyway, it opened Android-specific Camera-related system application. It is almost what I'd like to achieve.

So, how do I open a file in some 3rd party program from my code, giving user a choice?

Comment: "How do I implement such behavior?" -- start an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, where the "data" facet of the `Intent` is a `Uri` that points to your instructions. Of the two formats, PDF is more likely to be something the user can view than is an ODT... and HTML would be far better than either of those.

Comment: Oh right, pdf has almost native and extensive support: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170975/show-pdf-file-in-app